# presenting UIAlertController disturbs UI controls positions

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uialertcontroller

[image]I am developing iPhone application with iOS8. I used the UIAlertController to present an action sheet and it disturbs position of UI controls. I tried lot of options but still didn't get solution can anybody help me to solve the issue, Have uploaded screen shots before alert controller and after alert controller presented?[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is because you are using UIAlertController? Can you please elaborate and tell what exactly is happening. Are you using UITableviewcell for the view visible behind the UIAlertController??

Comment: Not sure but I think so, because before appearing of UIAlertController, UI is perfect but when it appears label frame goes change and I didn't use any table view in this view controller.

Comment: Can you show how the view looks before you present UIAlertController?

Comment: Ok now you can see both of before and after alert controller appears.

Comment: Please provide the code you used for presenting the     UIAlertController